# Mazda Demio fuel gauge not working

Tags: fuel-system, mazda, gasoline

Everytime I fill up it runs out quite quickly and I’ve just recently tried to fill up again and the reading hasn’t moved at all... help me?

it’s a Mazda demio 2010 I haven’t had it for very long but it’s been working fine before this happened (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej6O0.jpg)

Comment: When you fill up, how many litres does it take?

Comment: Um I put in about $50 and it pretty much fills from the first quarter line all the way up

Comment: Don’t understand your question - « reading hasn’t moved » but you have just replied that it goes from 1/4 to full...